# Averaging data to produce plots with geom_contour_filled

Tags: r

I'm looking to calculate the average of a value (z) across a range of x and y combinations so I can plot it.

I'm using the `geom_contour_filled` to make a map of model selection measure across a range of parameter values.  Unfortunately, I have multiple x and y values for each z and the help function for `geom_contour_filled` says "each unique combination of x and y can appear exactly once."  I tested it out and `ggplot` will plot my data without any warning, even though there are repeat values (not good, but I'm glad I caught it).  It turns out that for each x-y combo, it just plots the z value for the last time that value occurs in the dataset. See here:

```
# generate data
set.seed(1)
AIC <- runif(18)
param1 <- c(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3))
param2 <- c(c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3))

# plot the first round of parameter combos without repeats
testData <- data.frame(param1 = param1[1:9],
                       param2 = param2[1:9],
                       AIC = AIC[1:9])
ggplot(testData) +
  geom_contour_filled(aes(x = param1, y = param2, z = AIC))

# plot the second round of parameter combos (i.e. same x and y, different z)
testData <- data.frame(param1 = param1[10:18],
                       param2 = param2[10:18],
                       AIC = AIC[10:18])
ggplot(testData) +
  geom_contour_filled(aes(x = param1, y = param2, z = AIC))

# plot all data
testData <- data.frame(param1 = param1,
                       param2 = param2,
                       AIC = AIC)
ggplot(testData) +
  geom_contour_filled(aes(x = param1, y = param2, z = AIC))
```

The second and third plots above are the same, but I want the third to be the average of the first and second.  This means I need to calculate an average z value for each of my x and y parameter combinations first, and *then* use `geom_contour_filled`.

Anyone have an easy way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  It was just a matter of using a `group_by` and piping it into a `summarise` to calculate the mean AIC score.

```
set.seed(1)
AIC <- runif(18)
param1 <- c(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3))
param2 <- c(c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3))

testData <- data.frame(param1 = param1,
                       param2 = param2,
                       AIC = AIC)
ggplot(testData %>%
         group_by(param1, param2) %>%
         summarise(AIC = mean(AIC))) +
  geom_contour_filled(aes(x = param1, y = param2, z = AIC))
```